# Register new game for YouTube Gaming

Tags: youtube, schema, google-search, structured-data, google-search-console

We're developers of mobile device games.

I'm looking for solution how to add our game into list of games on youtube. We would like to use name of the game below video on youtube.

I have read many posts and articles about that, but I stuck on issue when YouTube doesn't see our game.

1. I added our website of the game to the Google Search Console and verified it. (OK) http://armoredaces.com
2. Create Schema.org (VideoGame) and put on the website. (OK) https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/#url=armoredaces.com
3. Google crawled and indexed our page and see our structured data. (OK)
4. Granted to YouTube permission to use data from Google Search Console (same accounts for Google Search Console and Youtube Channel) (OK)
5. Set the video category to the "Games" and select our game... (Here we are stuck)

Do you know what is wrong? Google index our website on 2/3/2017, google search console see our structured data and it is valid.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Same problem here and haven't been able to find any answers.

Comment: It would appear that the game is now listed. Would you mind sharing what else you did or how long it took? https://i.imgur.com/pcSBpOb.png I get the impression that having your game on Google Play store makes it appear there without problems, which developers I know have problems getting their Steam or self-published games in the list.

Answer (score 1):

3 years of on and off searching later, I have finally figured out the solution to this for my own game, which is now listed.

Google crawls Wikipedia or Steam. If your game is on either platform, it should show up. We made a wiki page that got approved, and 1-3 weeks later it became a category on Youtube.

I then wrote to artist-support@youtube.com to get my logo and banner added to the category, which 2 months later, they did.